# PDF text fields not functioning on webpage

Tags: html, pdf, embed

I created a PDF in Adobe Acrobat DC. It is a registration form for our event. So it has text fields that the user fills out. I have attempted to embed  this file and it works with this while on a computer.

```
<embed src="Registration2017OP.pdf" width="800" height="1000"></embed>
```

But my problem or one of them is, when I attempt to open this on a mobile device the text fields are no longer editable. Any clues why?

I tried using ViewrJS and the same thing, except whether I am using a computer or mobile the fields are never editable.
[link to registration where fields are not editable](http://hotraqs.com/ViewerJS/#../Registration2017OP.pdf)

I have also tried google docs with the same results. Maybe I am going about this whole registration form wrong, but why are the fields not editable?

Answer (score 0):

The majority of the browsers and PDF viewers on mobile devices are too dumb to properly deal with fields. In your situation, you have a web browser, which most likely can not link in any way to a smart enough PDF viewer.

Comment: A workaround… not really… The best you can do is to not embed, but to make the form available as a separate download. That would at least allow to eliminate the web browser's PDF viewers. In addition, you would put a note on the form stating that the viewer may not enable the user to properly fill out the form; with a smart form, you could then hide that note, and unlock more intelligence for the form when the PDF viewer supports (Acrobat) JavaScript.